# Retrieving previously focused element

Tags: javascript

I would like to find out, in Javascript, which previous element had focus as opposed to the current focus. I've been looking through the DOM and haven't found what I need, yet. Is there a way to do this any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each time an element is focused, you'd have to store which one it was. Then when another element is focused, you could retrieve the variable for the previous focused element.

So basically, your **single** focus handler would do **2 things**:

1. Check if previousFocus is defined. If it is, retrieve it.
2. Set previousFocus to the currently focused element.

Here is a quick demo with jQuery (you can use raw JS too... just fewer lines w jQuery, so it's easier to understand imo):

```
  // create an anonymous function that we call immediately
  // this will hold our previous focus variable, so we don't
  // clutter the global scope
(function() {

      // the variable to hold the previously focused element
    var prevFocus;

      // our single focus event handler
    $("input").focus(function() {

          // let's check if the previous focus has already been defined
        if (typeof prevFocus  !== "undefined") {

              // we do something with the previously focused element
            $("#prev").html(prevFocus.val());
        }

          // AFTER we check upon the previously focused element
          //   we (re)define the previously focused element
          //   for use in the next focus event
        prevFocus = $(this);
    });
})();
```

### [**working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EzPfK/)

Answer (score 11):

Just found this question while solving the exact same problem and realised it was so old the jQuery world has moved on a bit :)

This should provide a more effective version of `Peter Ajtai`s code, as it will use only a single delegated event handler (not one per input element).

```
// prime with empty jQuery object
window.prevFocus = $();

// Catch any bubbling focusin events (focus does not bubble)
$(document).on('focusin', ':input', function () {

    // Test: Show the previous value/text so we know it works!
    $("#prev").html(prevFocus.val() || prevFocus.text());

    // Save the previously clicked value for later
    window.prevFocus = $(this);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/EzPfK/80/

**Notes:**

- Uses $() to create an empty jQuery object (allows it to be used immediately).
- As this one uses the jQuery `:input` selector it works with `select` & `button` elements as well as inputs.
- It does not need a DOM ready handler as `document` is always present.
- As the previously focused control is required "elsehere" is is simply stored on `window` for global use, so it does not need an IIFE function wrapper.

Comment: `focusin` doesn't work in Firefox [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin)

Comment: @Michel: Have you tried this with jQuery (which usually compensates for broken browser implementations)? I just tried my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/EzPfK/80/ with FireFox and it works just fine. :)

Comment: Really Useful also working in FireFox and Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Well depending on what else your page is doing, it could be tricky, but for starters you could have a "blur" event handler attached to the `<body>` element that just stashes the event target.

Answer (score 1):

To me this seems a slight improvement on Gone Coding's answer:

```
window.currFocus = document;
// Catch focusin 
$(window).on( 'focusin', function () {
  window.prevFocus = window.currFocus;
  console.log( '£ prevFocus set to:');
  console.log( window.currFocus );
  window.currFocus = document.activeElement;
});
```

... there's no stipulation in the question that we're talking exclusively about `INPUT`s here: it says "previous elements".  The above code would also include recording focus of things like `BUTTON`s, or anything capable of getting focus.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('message-text-area').addEventListener('focus',
  event => console.log('FOCUS!')
);
```

`event.relatedTarget` has all the data about the previously focused element.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach which watches both `focusin` and `focusout`, in this case to prevent focus to a class of inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="xyz" value="abc" readonly class="nofocus">
<script>
$(function() {
        var leaving = $(document);
        $(document).on('focusout', function(e) {
                leaving = e.target;
        });
        $( '.nofocus' ).on('focusin', function(e) {
                leaving.focus();
        });
        $( '.nofocus' ).attr('tabIndex', -1);
});
</script>
```

Setting `tabIndex` prevents keyboard users from "getting stuck".