# Onblur prevents onsubmit while submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, validation

i have validation functions which is being called on `onblur` of respective input field. at the same time i am calling same validation functions with one say `validateall()` function and `validateall()` is being called on `onsubmit`.
now the problem is if some error has occured and i have corrected it and submit the form at that time `onblur` is being called which is preventing from calling `onsubmit` event.
this problem i am facing in Firefox only.

javascript:

```
function validateFormOnSubmit(theForm) 
{
vUsername(theForm.userName,document.getElementById('UError'));//this will return true or false depends on error occurrence. 
}
```

html:

```
<form name="form" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this);">
<input type="text" id="userName" onblur="vUsername(this,UError);">
```

//UError is div id where i'll be printing error msgs.

Comment: Post some codes what you've tried so far

Comment: i have edited the question. plz have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Use delay() function or setTimeOut() function for onBlur.

this link also helps you..
[jQuery validation onblur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622232/jquery-validation-onblur)

Answer (score 0):

Add a setTimeout-function to your onBlur-event. To hand over your parameters you have to use a anonymous function:

```
<input type="text" id="userName" onblur="setTimeout(function(){ vUsername(this,UError) }, 200);">
```

Now your submit-event should be faster than onBlur :-)

Comment: You could use onFocus instead of onBlur:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639908/retrieving-previously-focused-element